# get src of child Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `img` tag inside a `a` tag. If I hover the a tag then i want to alert the src of the img tag, and delete the last 4 characters of it.

HTML:

```
<a onmouseover="hoverImage($(this))">
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" height="24" alt="" title="" />
    <p>Startseite</p>
</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
function hoverImage (e) {
 alert(e.find('img').getAttribute('src'));
}
```

I tried my best but don't work :(

http://jsfiddle.net/opvryy00/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

HTML

```
<a >
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" height="24" alt="" title="" />
    <p>Startseite</p>
</a>
```

JS

```
$( "a" ).mouseover(function() {
   var src=$(this).find("img").prop('src');
    src=src.slice(0,-4);
    alert(src)
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opvryy00/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Do not use inline JavaScript: it is really ugly and obsolete, since that you can do all you want using a script.

Remove your `onmouseover="..."` attribute in the HTML, add an id to your link and use Javascript to listen to the event, like this:

HTML:

```
<a id="my-link">
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" height="24" alt="" title="" />
    <p>Startseite</p>
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function hoverImage(e) {
    var img = $(e.target).find('img');
    alert(img.getAttribute('src'));

    // Delete the last 4 characters
    img.setAttribute('src', el.getAttribute('src').slice(0, -4));
}

$("#my-link").mouseover(hoverImage);
```

Comment: where is remove 4last character from src?

Comment: @ashkufaraz I just added it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').mouseover(function(){
    alert($(this).find('img').attr('src').slice(0, -4));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this code. You can remove onmouseover attribute inside a tag.

**HTML**

```
<a>
  <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" height="24" alt="" title="" />
  <p>Startseite</p>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(function()
{
  $('a').mouseover(function(){
     var str = $(this).find('img').attr('src');             
      var new_str = str.substring(0,str.length - 4);
      alert(new_str);
  });      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you adapt your approach a little, let's remove the inline javascript and target the image directly. Also, lets avoid an alert, you can see the result appear below your anchor.

**HTML**

```
<a>
    <img src="https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png" height="24" alt="" title="" />
    <p>Startseite</p>
</a>
<div class="output"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var hoverImage = function(e) {
    var $img = $(e.currentTarget),
        src = $img.attr('src'),
        newSource;

    newSource = src.substring(0, src.length - 4);

    $('.output').html(newSource);
}

$(document).on('ready', function() {
    $('img').hover(hoverImage);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/_naz/u2f2qeaw/